# Find the Fourier Series of $f(x)=1-6x^2+4x^3$

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Define $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by letting $f(x)=1-6x^2+4x^3$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$, and requiring that $f(x+2)=f(x)$ and $f(-x)=f(x) \ \ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. Find the Fourier series $Sf(x)$ [**Hint:** consider $f'(0), f '(1),f '''(x)$].

This question is part (b) of a question. For part (a), I was required to graph $f(x)$ for $-2\leq x\leq 3$. I believe I have done this correctly, but am wondering if this can help solve the above problem.

I'm unsure of how to properly utilise the 'hint' to find $Sf(x)$. I have calculated 
$$f '(0)=0$$
$$f '(1)=0$$
$$f ''' (x)=24$$
How does this help to find the Fourier Series of f?

Comment: Do you know the Fourier series for the constant $24$?  How could you use that?  Also, you computed $f'''(x)$ for $0 < x < 1$, but what is it elsewhere?

Comment: Thank you for your response. To be honest, I don't know the Fourier series for 24. Is this something that is unique? Or can it be generalised to other positive integers? Is $f '''(x)=0$ elsewhere?

Comment: If $f(-x)=f(x)$, what does  that tell you about $f'''(x)$?

Comment: I've had a think and i'm really not too sure. I'm curious to know the answer.